# What is up with those blurry sides on a photo?

Tags: photo-editing

What is the reason for making those blurry sides? What is this technique called?
To me it is very annoying.

I read some answers on Quora, and it seems a lot of people do not like it.
If you have to fill a certain space for the the picture and don't like the black side-bars, why can't you just crop it?

[image]

Comment: One place where I have seen that many times (and done it myself 1 time and instantly hated it so I stopped) is on Instagram where you are forced to upload vertical images on a 4:5 aspect ratio. Sometimes you want to retain the original aspect ratio (2:3 in my case) so instead of adding a black or white or any other solid color borders to fill the gap, you create this blurred fill effect.

Comment: *why can't you just crop it?* - How would you crop that example picture your posted to fit the 16:9 aspect ratio that the whole image shows? You *could* crop it but you would basically need to keep only the kangaroo's head in the frame (or any other part but in any case, the composition / framing would be *very* different).

Comment: PS. For anyone curious, this is [Roger, the famously ripped kangaroo](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/world/roger-the-famously-ripped-kangaroo-has-died-after-a-lovely-long-life/SOQOWMNWCIYOJLWX5MK3QYMJPQ/).

Comment: @MrUpsidown, this serie of photos is probably heavy cropped: https://www.businessinsider.com/roger-the-super-buff-kangaroo-died-2018-12

Comment: @MrUpsidown, Yes you are right I was more thinking about adjusting the space where the picture will be placed. But I understand that it's driven by the website / app. I was really more asking if there is some aesthetic effect to it - a reason other than just being a filler. (And why would anyone like this effect?)

Comment: *Is there some aesthetic effect to it?* - well... that is a question of taste I suppose. Now your question sits closer to web design than photography I think (as I can't remember having seen this effect applied to anything else than websites/apps - whether on videos or stills). I don't think there is any reason for this aside aesthetics but I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This image is just a frame from video (IMHO)

The filter is used in videos when the original video is vertical and the user want to upload it in platforms which support mainly horizontal video. In DaVinci Resolve this effect is named "Blanking Fill". You can see how to apply it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8-gNkDT3HU).

Comment: so if you don't fill the space the video cannot be uploaded? Or will it just be black (or white)?

Comment: @birdpoolcleaner, it depend on platform. On some you can upload it (and have it with black strips). Other may not permit you upload.

Comment: I have seen websites displaying images that way. Not only on videos.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, possible, but looks odd and unpleasant for me.

Comment: It's once again time to remind people of the [Vertical Video Syndrome PSA](https://youtu.be/dechvhb0Meo)  Think about old Mila Kunis!!!!

Comment: Television is one such place, and the empty space has to be filled with *something*. Instead of solid colour, this fakes a wider blurred image from the central part. Someone in the duplicate says "lack of planning ahead" but in some cases you really do want portrait mode (perhaps not expecting it to be 'shared').